# Postman form-data: How to program it inside a HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, postman, multipartform-data

I am doing a request through postman to a specific url but I set the form-data type in order to get data to the site like this:

[image]

Now I want to program this request inside C# but everything I tried so far is returning a 400 Bad Request response. This is what I tried:

```
public async Task<CheckAccessTokenModel> CheckAccessTokenAsync(string accessToken)
{

    string uriString = "someurl";
    var uri = new Uri(uriString);

    try
    {
        using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = uri
            };

            var ClientId = ConfigurationAccessor.Configuration["WebCredentials:ClientId"];
            var Secret = ConfigurationAccessor.Configuration["WebCredentials:Secret"];
            var authString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{ClientId}:{Secret}"));

            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authString);
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new StringContent("token"), accessToken);

            request.Content = content;
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            var checkTokenResponseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //return new CheckAccessTokenModel { Active = true, Exp = 1647431224233 };
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckAccessTokenModel>(checkTokenResponseData);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am doing it with the MultipartFormDataContent Object as suggested by many others here but it still won't work.
What can be the problem here?

EDIT: Wrong picture replaced

Comment: the data in request can not be processed by the endpoint, whatever you are sending is not what the endpoint is expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply

```
request.Content = new StringContent($"token={accessToken}");
```

With form data I think it's something like this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"token", acccessToken}
};

using var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
request.Content = content;
```

Comment: Hi, the token I pass is not null. I think you do not understand what I am doing here. The access token gets passed inside this function from previous function calls. Now I need to take this token and send it to another webserver in order to check if its still available you know. All values are present nothing is null.

Also the error message of the response says Mssing request parameter 'token', it should be included thorugh my code. I need to do it with the form-data type

Comment: Thank you very much! The second variant is the right one. I am going to memorize this one somewhere deep in my mind